# Logging to azure blob store in a stand-alone application

Tags: c#, logging, azure

I want to send Tracer output to Azure blob store, but the application is not deployable to Azure, it must run as a standalone application. Is there a relatively easy way to do this? Everything I've seen talks about logging in Azure if you're running as some sort of deployed Azure role. Ideally, I want a Trace.Listeners.Add call and/or something in app.config that solves this.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly create a trace listener to writes to Windows Azure Storage and use that from any application as long as it will have the ability to access the REST endpoints for the Storage system in Windows Azure.  In fact, Steve Marx posted something on [his blog](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/lightweight-tracing-to-windows-azure-tables) that could give you a head start.

I would suggest that for something like a trace writer I would recommend looking at writing the messages to Table storage (like Steve's post) rather than BLOB storage, unless you are wanting to batch up a lot of messages locally to the application and then write them all as a file to BLOB storage.

Comment: I'm embarrassed that I didn't think of this use case when I wrote my TableTraceListener, so it requires the storage connection string to be in a Windows Azure configuration setting (not available when running outside of Windows Azure). This is a mistake on my part; sorry. But the code should get you most of the way there.